# Functions argument default value

Tags: javascript

```
function foo( a, b ) {

  a = a || '123';
  b = b || 55;  
  document.write( a + ',' + b );
}

foo(); // prints: 123,55
foo('bar'); // prints: bar,55
foo('x', 'y'); // prints x,y
```

but:

```
foo(0,''); // prints: 123,55
```

why dont it print 0 ,55?

Comment: `0` is falsy. I'd use `var a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : '123';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `||` tests for *truthiness*, and `0` is among the values that are considered to be `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the value [`0` is a "falsy" value](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) and is considered a `false`

Answer (score 2):

0 and "" also compute to false when checked. Hence you need to change your condition to

```
a = a != null ? a : '123';
b = b != null ? a : 55;
```